# How to write a python dictionary to a json file in the following format?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

so I have a python dictionary in the form of {'key1':[value1, value2]},
I hope to write it to a json file in the format of:

```
{
   "key1": [value1, value2],
   "key2": [value, value],
   ....
}
```

I am currently using json.dump(dictionary, file_to_write_to), and the output looks like:

```
{"key1": [value1, value2], "key2": [value, value]}
```

Comment: `json.dump(dictionary, file_to_write_to, indent=4)`

Answer (score 0):

Use json pretty print as defined here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

From simplejson documentation (see pretty print) https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4 * ' '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Comment: This will produce result like this, which is not what I expected.
` 
   "google.com": [
              17.359, 
              42.282
     ],
`

Comment: Ahh the format of the comment I made above just messed up. Basically 17.359 and 42.282 got split into two separate lines, which is not what i expected it to be